# In Bash, how to define a list of directories and iterate through them?

Tags: bash, shell, validation, debugging, directory

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a DIR=("/Volumes/drive1", "/Volumes/drive2", "~/temp", "~/file1")

[ -d "/Volumes/drive1" ] && echo "[DEBUG] 1"

#set -x ## DEBUG

for d in "${DIR[@]}"; do
    [ -d "${d}" ] && echo "[DEBUG] 2 ${d}"
done
```

When I run the script, it prints `1` but not `2`.

I've looked up on the Web for tutorials on directory validation and iterating through list of files and directories but still could not figure out what's wrong with my code. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: You can find this kind of error, by turning on tracing (`set -x`).

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: Note that ALL_UPPERCASE variable names like `DIR` are potentially dangerous.  They can clash with the many special ALL_UPPERCASE variables that are used in shell programs.  See [Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/673055/4154375).  Names like `dir` are generally safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need your tildes (`~`) to be unquoted:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a DIR=( "/Volumes/drive1" "/Volumes/drive2" ~/"temp" ~/"file1" )

[[ -d /Volumes/drive1 ]] && echo "[DEBUG] 1"

for d in "${DIR[@]}"; do
    [[ -d $d ]] && echo "[DEBUG] 2 ${d}"
done
```

---

**There's no commas between items in an array in bash.**

---

```
declare -a DIR=( "/Volumes/drive1" "/Volumes/drive2" ~/"temp" ~/"file1" )
```

can be written just:

```
DIR=( /Volumes/drive1 /Volumes/drive2 ~/temp ~/file1 )
```

---

Always first test your script to https://shellcheck.net before asking here.

---

`[[` is a bash keyword similar to (but more powerful than) the `[` command. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals. Unless you're writing for POSIX sh, I recommend `[[`